# Given skewed distributions, combine them to maximize probabilty if positive sum

Tags: statistics

(I'm not certain if this belong here or on CrossValidated; it is a question on statistics, but fairly pure. Sorry if it should be moved!)

Given some list of normal distributions, $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ each with means $E_i$ and variances $V_i$, we want to assign weights to the distributions to maximize the probability that their sum will be positive. That is, to find some $w_i$s such that
$$P\left(\sum_i w_i X_i > 0\right)$$
is maximal. The answer to this problem is straightforward: set each $w_i$ to $E_i/V_i$.

In an extension of this problem where we additionally have the whole covariance matrix $V_{ij}$, the solution has a natural parallel when we recognize the linearity: the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix are uncorrelated, with eigenvalues equal to their variance, which reduces it to the previous problem. Thus the weight vector $\mathbf{W} = \mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{E} $.

Consider the problem, though, when the distributions also have some skewness (and thus cannot be normal -- so let's assume instead, for instance, that they are skew normal distributions). Given the expectations, covariances, and skews of the different variables, what set of weights is optimal?

Comment: I don't see why your first paragraph is correct. If $X_1$ is 100001 with probability $10^{-6}$ and $1$ with probability $1 - 10^{-6}$ ,then $\mathbb{E}X_1 = 2$, but the variance is roughly $10^6$. If $X_2$ takes values $-2$ and $+4$ with equal probability, then $\mathbb{E}X_2 = 1$, but the variance of $X_2$ is $9$. Your posting suggests you should form ${2\over{10^6}}X_1 + {1\over9}X_2$, but of course you do much better with ${3\over4}X_1 + {1\over4}X_2$ for example. Also: are you assuming the $X_i$ are independent?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry! I completely meant to say "Give some list of _normal_ distributions...". You're quite right of course that in general that's not the best answer, hence my question: when the distributions aren't normal, e.g. we know their skew in addition to mean and variance, trying to find out the best set of weights. :) I'll edit the original post

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the result can be written in a closed form. The best I can do is the following. Let $F_i(p)$ is a Fourier transformed distribution of $X_i$ then one can find $w_i$ from a set of non-linear equations
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[\prod_{k=1}^N F_k(\alpha w_k)\right] \frac{F_i'(\alpha w_i)}{F_i(\alpha w_i)}d\alpha=0
$$
for gaussian case $$F_i(p)=e^{-p^2 V_i/2+i E_i p}$$ (up to an irrelevant constant factor)
$$F_i'(p)=F_i(p)(-pV_i-i E_i)$$
you can evaluate the integral in $\alpha$ to get (up to a factor)
$$
A E_i-B V_i w_i = 0
$$
which gives your result up to an (irrelevant) simultaneous rescaling of all $w_i$
For an arbitrary distribution you can easily solve the system numerically. It is just a single integral to compute for each $w_i$.

Alternatively one can do perturbative expansion in skewness.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks. I'll read up on Fourier transformations of distributions some more (I was only tangentially aware of the idea.) How would the perturbative expansion look? Even if only to first order?